# Why do Haskell functors only have derived types in their target category?

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, the Functor typeclass functor is defined as follows (see e.g. [Haskell wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Functors_on_Hask)):

```
class Functor (f :: * -> *) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

As far as I understand (please correct me if I am wrong), such a functor can only have as target category a category constructed using a type constructor, e.g. `[]`, `Maybe`, etc. On the other hand, one may think of functors having any category as target of a functor, e.g. the category of all Haskell types.
For example, `Int` could be an object in the target category of a functor, not just `Maybe Int` or `[Int]`.

What is the motivation for this restriction on Haskell functors?

Comment: Simplicity? Haskell doesn't have first class type functions so all functions are really just type constructors.

Comment: @jozefg: Pardon my ignorance: what are "first class type functions"?

Comment: So in that function we're tossing around an `f` right? And in your scenario, `f` should be just like a normal Haskell function and map types to types. In Haskell, the only things that are allowed to have the kind `* -> *` are type constructors. Type families are more general, but they must always be fully applied

Comment: [This question is related.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177967/why-doesnt-haskell-have-type-level-lambda-abstractions?rq=1)

Comment: @jozefg: I occasionally think about this question again and again. I suppose the Haskell restriction does not affect the expressive power of functors. For example, suppose that we have a functor that is isomorphic to the list functor, but does not map, say, Int -> [Int] but Int -> <fancy type using no type constructor>. Then I guess one could prove that <fancy type using no type constructor> is isomorphic to [Int]. So choosing objects that are defined using a type constructor is just convenient and does not sacrifice the expressive power.

Answer (score 1):

There's no restriction at all! When I started learning the category-theoretic basis for type constructors, this very point confused me as well. We'll get to that. But first, let me clear up some confusion. These two quotes:

> such a functor can only have as target category a category constructed using a type constructor

and

> one may think of functors having any category as target of a functor, e.g. the category of all Haskell types

show that you are misunderstanding what a functor is (or at the very least, you are misusing terminology).

Functors do not *construct* categories. A functor is a mapping *between* categories. Functors bring objects and morphisms (types and functions) in the source category to object and morphisms in the target category.

Note that this means a functor is really a *pair* of mappings: a mapping on objects *F_obj* and mapping on morphisms *F_morph*. In Haskell, the object part *F_obj* of the functor is the name of the type constructor (e.g. `List`), while the morphism part is the function `fmap` (it is up to the Haskell compiler to sort out which `fmap` we are referring to in any given expression). Thus, we cannot say that `List` is a functor; only the combination of `List` and `fmap` is a functor. Still, people abuse notation; programmers call `List` a functor, while category theorists use the same symbol to refer to both parts of the functor.

Furthermore, in programming, almost all functors are *endofunctors*, that is, the source and target category are the same - the category of all types in our language. Let's call this category **Type**. An endofunctor *F* on **Type** maps a type *T* to another type *FT* and a function *T -> S* to another function *FT -> FS*. This mapping must of course obey the functor laws.

Using `List` as an example: we have a type constructor `List : Type -> Type`, and a function `fmap: (a -> b) -> (List a -> List b)`, that together form a functor. T

There is one final point to clear up. Writing `List int` does not *create* a new type of lists of integers. *This type already existed*. It was an object in our category **Type**. `List Int` is simply a way to refer to it.

Now, you're wondering why a functor can't map a type to, say, `Int` or `String`. But, it can! One just has to use the identity functor. For any category *C*, the identity functor maps every object to itself and morphism to itself. It is straightforward to verify this mapping satisfies the functor laws. In Haskell, this would be a type constructor `id : * -> *` that maps every type to itself. For example, `id int` evaluates to `int`.

Moreover, one can even create *constant* functors, that map all types to a single type. For example, the functor `ToInt : * -> *`, where `ToInt a = int` for all types `a`, and maps all morphisms to the integer identity function:  `fmap f = \x -> x`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this question is over two years old. "Functors do not construct categories.": I did not say that. I said that functors map two categories, where the target category must have the form `f a`, where `f` is, as far as I know, a type constructor. From what I remember from category theory, this must be some kind of canonical representation (initial object in a category of categories? maybe I am misusing the terminology.) Anyway, I will read your answer carefully. Many thanks.

Comment: @Giorgio whoops, I didn't notice how old it was haha. It just showed up in "unanswered questions". I'm not sure what you mean by "canonical representation". As far as I know (and I could be wrong here), there is not a relationship between functors and initial/terminal objects.

Comment: I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_algebra (see Use in computer science). In Haskell (most) functors are defined on an algebraic data types. The target object of such a functor is an initial algebra. The initial algebra is isomorphic to the set of terms built using the value constructors. E.g., for lists, `[]` and `:`. I meant this by canonical representation.

Comment: Yeah, I know what an initial object is, and that inductive datatypes are initial objects in the F-algebra of a category. You're correct that many type-constructors are defined inductively. But this is *not* strictly necessary. For example, the functor `(_, int)` that takes a type `a` to the product type `(a, int)` and a function `f : 'a -> 'b` to `g : 'a * int -> 'a * int` is not inductive.

Comment: Did you mean: "takes ... a function `f : 'a -> 'b` to `g : 'a * int -> 'b * int`?

Comment: @Giorgio Whoops. Yes, that is what I meant.